# Обратится с другого сайта и сосчитать значения сессии в php

Tags: php, сессия, golang

Добрый день.

Пишу основную часть сайта на php,а дополнительную 
 (чат/вебсокетная часть/файлсервер для более быстрой отдачи) на golang.
 Может показаться извращением, но хочу попробовать сделать следующее.
 Человек заходит на пхп сервер- получает страничку, 
 затем джаваскрипт начинает подключаться по вебсокетам к серверу на go.

Надо как-то сообщить этому серверу, что этот пользователь,скажем, Вася, а этот - Петя.

Была проблемка с передачей куков вообще по вебсокетам. Я сделал немного по другому: При подключении я пишу

```
var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2000/sock/12345");
```

т.е. 12345- это айдишник пользователя, который подключился. Теперь сервер знает, что под данным сокетом сидит пользователь 12345. Всё вроде хорошо.
                Но естественно, если сюда заглянет программист- он может всё поломать.
                Я хочу передать название сессии, например

```
localhost:2000/sock/sessionName
```

Go сервер должен на какуюнибудь скрытую страничку php сервера послать запрос: *Скажи-ка, а есть ли такая сессия, если да- то дай мне айдишник человека*.
                Ну как-то так.
                Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое сделать.
                Спасибо.

Comment: А почему бы Go-серверу просто не обратиться непосредственно к базе данных, в которой эта самая сессия хранится, вместо php-скрипта?

Comment: Потому что сессия обычно храниться не в базе, если речь идет о $_SESSION.

Comment: @GrayHoax, помоему это было *предложение* хранить сессию в базе. Абсолютно логичное в данном контексте.

Comment: @artoodetoo, Да, понятно, но давать лезть в саму базу несекьюрно! Наиболее безопасно использовать REST или подобие.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд достаточно просто было бы использовать JSON для передачи информации по пользователю. Но надо понимать, что ограничения подключения сервер-сервер должны настраиваться дополнительно, например в iptables.

Как я вижу работу вашего приложения:

1. Пользователь логиниться на сервере, ему присваевается сессия.
2. Браузер обращается на go сервер и передает туже самую строку `var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2000/sock/12345");`
3. Go сервер смотрит и видит, что она новая, и обращается на php сервер запросом к скрипту `/check_session.php`
4. PHP сервер отдает нужные go серверу параметры с помощью json_encode
5. На основании переданных данных go сервер решает обслуживать ли дальше клиента и кто он есть)

Если совсем параноить - данные между серверами можно шифровать с помощью открытого ключа, а на go сервере расшифровывать закрытым. Секьюрно)